# Read file while preserving format and type

Tags: ruby

How do I preserve the format and type of the original data stored in a file?

```
stored_response = File.open('spec/data/response.txt', 'rb') { |f| f.read }
item.get_location.should == stored_response
```

`#get_location` being an api call

response.txt contains [this](https://gist.github.com/4501489) but returns [this](https://gist.github.com/4501471) once read

Comment: Well, there's a newline in your file. Now you can see it.

Comment: You want to unserialize the json, and you want to pretty print it again?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev there's actually no new line in the file. Copied from vim ---- 1 [990] ---- "1" being the line number and the only line number.

Comment: I don't think you want `'rb'` there, that means read binary. You could just write `File.read('data.json')`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't escape the characters in the string itself, it just escapes them when you `inspect` the string (which is what `irb` does when it prints the result).

Try using `puts` to inspect the data.

```
irb:001:0> contents = File.read("data.json")
=> "[990]\n"

irb:002:0> puts contents
[990]
=> nil
```

Comment: I'm setting `File.open('data.json', 'rb') { |f| f.read }` to a variable and using that as my expectation in a test. What the variable returns is the escaped text.

Comment: The expectation will print the value with `inspect` too. Try putting `puts variable` after you read the file and see what you get. I promise you that `read` doesn't escape anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with json, why not open it as json?

```
JSON.parse(IO.read("data.json"))
```

You won't see any *serialization artifacts* of that JSON File then.